# how to change the width of a <hr> element in one direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the width of a `<hr>` element with jQuery but it changes the width in 2 directions. I only want it to stretch to the right side. the variable food.runningDistance changes when I do some actions on my application.  Code :

html :

```
<hr id="runningLine">
```

javascript :

```
$("#runningLine").animate({width: food.runningDistance}, 500);
```

Comment: do you want to `animate` <hr> from left to right?

Comment: @Alrazah: `hr` has semantic meaning, `div` does not.

Comment: right @T.J.Crowder why would you use an element which is used to "mark" an end of a paragraph for other purposes than that?

Comment: @Alrazah: Hmmm, re-reading the question, I see what you mean -- it's not hyper-clear, but it does look like it's not being used for its semantic purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `hr` element behaves like `margin: 0 auto` is set to it. As I stated in my comment to your question, I would use a `div` since `hr` is [supposed to mark a thematic break](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element), but you're using it for a different purpose.

If you still want to get it work the way you want, you have to set `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;`:

```js
$("#runningLine").css("margin", 0).animate({width: "10%"}, 3000);
```

```html
<hr id="runningLine">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```